# How to DIE all LIVE'S in a dialog when close?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jquery

I have a dialog $('.dialog'), then a fill with an html of the form when I open it:

```
$('.dialog').html(getForm());
```

Then I have a function named close(); When I click close I do:

```
$('.dialog').html('');
$('.dialog').hide();
```

BUT, if in the form I put dynamic elements (new DOM), with .live('event',function(){})...
when I open the dialog again I get the live action attached two times, if I close the dialog and open again I get the live action attached three times, etc. (Please UNDERSTAND that I need to use .live() and not .bind())

THE FORM:

```
<form id="formid">
<input type="text" class="please_only_onetime"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.please_only_onetime').live('focusin', function(){ alert( 'one time' );});
});
</script>
</form>
```

Finally, if I put the following before the .live(), the code works well:

```
$('.please_only_onetime').die();
```

BUT, What I want is to generalize this in close() function like:

```
$('.dialog').find('*').die() // but this seems not to be working!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.dialog').delegate('.please_only_onetime', 'focusin', function () {
  //this is all you need to do... no rebinding, no "die"'ing ...
});
```

Or for simplicity you can keep using `live`.  I think you should make the switch to `delegate()` though.

Comment: Yes, ".delegate()" is really better than ".live()" anyway.

Comment: +1 for `.delegate()`. The fact that this is better than `.live()` in most (if not all) situations really must be burnt to every jQuery programmer's mind with a searing conviction.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ".live()", you don't have to re-attach the event handlers.  That's the whole point.  Just attach them at the start, and then they'll keep working no matter how many times you load and unload the form.